# c# windows 8 selected comboboxitem

Tags: c#, windows-8, combobox

I'm developping a Windows 8 Store Application (c#).
I have a Combobox (cboTeam1) that gets the items from a repository.

```
private static List<TeamItem> JPLItems = new List<TeamItem>();

public static List<TeamItem> getJPLItems()
    {
        if (JPLItems.Count == 0)
        {
            JPLItems.Add(new TeamItem() { Id = 1, Description = "Anderlecht", Image = "Jpl/Anderlecht.png", ItemType = ItemType.JPL });
            JPLItems.Add(new TeamItem() { Id = 1, Description = "Beerschot", Image = "Jpl/Beerschot.png", ItemType = ItemType.JPL });
            JPLItems.Add(new TeamItem() { Id = 1, Description = "Cercle Brugge", Image = "Jpl/Cercle.png", ItemType = ItemType.JPL });
            JPLItems.Add(new TeamItem() { Id = 1, Description = "Charleroi", Image = "Jpl/Charleroi.png", ItemType = ItemType.JPL });
        }
        return JPLItems;
    }
```

I load the items in the cboTeam1's ItemsSource:

```
cboTeam1.ItemsSource = ItemRepository.getJPLItems();
```

When cboTeam1 selectionchanged I do this:

```
    private void cboTeam1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ploeg1.Text = cboTeam1.SelectedValue.ToString();               
    }
```

This results in: **SportsBetting.Model.TeamItem**

Can anyone help me to get the combobox selectedvalue in my textblock (Ploeg1.Text)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've nearly answered this for yourself.

```
private void cboTeam1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        // cast the selected item to the correct type.
    var selected = cboTeam.SelectedValue as TeamItem;
        //then access the appropriate property on the object, in this case "Description"
        // note that checking for null would be a good idea, too.
    Ploeg1.Text = selected.Description;               
}
```

The other option would be to override ToString() in your TeamItem class to return Description.  In that case your original code should work fine.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this._description;  // assumes you have a backing store of this name
}
```

Comment: Wow why didn't I see this :)
Thank you very much!!

Comment: How can I check if the selected item from cboTeam1 is different from the selected item from cboTeam2?

Comment: Probably best to ask that as a new question. :)